# After moving bones and inserting keyframes, the animation doesn't work

Tags: animation, bones

I'm animating something right now and when I go into pose mode, and move the bones and inserted a keyframe and i go back to the first frame and play the animation, nothing happens, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: In the Timeline > Keying menu, have you chosen a transform in the Active Keying Set menu? Or is one of the Dope Sheet track locked? Maybe share your file (the armature only): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The way you describe it sounds like you only have one keyframe. You need at least 2 for a bone to do anything.